RRAS on a one-NIC server
I have two network zones, "private" and "public"
Public machines can access infrastructure services like SMTP, Samba, HTTPS etc.
Private machines can access public machines only.
I want to designate one public machine to act as a "gateway" for "port forwarding" for all private machines to access those external infra services.
As a UNIX guy, I have set it up in 10 minutes on Linux with iptables. Now, I must do it in Windows. Tried the following:
Cygwin netcat - works like a charm, which proves that Defender is passing left and right, and TCP flags are OK. But this was just a test, we need a Windows-native solution with persistent rules.
netsh - works as expected in my home lab (win2016 server as gateway) but doesn't on real Win2022 server, presumably I must disable TCP v6, massage v4tov4... Anyway, this was just a test
HyperV New-NetNat and Add-NetNatStaticMapping - could not figure out how to use them for my case. HyperV seems like overkill, anyway, as all machines are ESX VMs
RRAS - again, after reading 50 instructions how to use it for other cases (like remote access to internal infra), I doubt this is a proper tool for me. Installed it anyway. Added NAT... for one NIC only, as I have only one... What then? Where do I specify port, say, 25, and IP of the external SMTP server?
Is there any other way?
